# Is there a way to find the superposition of two Wigner functions without finding their density operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, quasiprobability-distributions

Say I have two Wigner functions $W_1(x,p)$ and $W_2(x,p)$ representing pure states on optical phase space, and I want to know what the Wigner function of their superposition $W_{1+2}(x,p)$ looks like (let's say an equal superposition for this case). Is there any way to combine the functions to find $W_{1+2}$ without decomposing $W_1$ and $W_2$ into their corresponding pure states $\rho_1=|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|$ and $\rho_2=|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|$ and then finding the Wigner function for the cross terms $|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_2|$?

Said another way, is there any way to explicitly find the interference fringes between two pure states on optical phase space without finding the density operators of those pure states?

Comment: You need the cross terms. An example of what you want to consider is the cat states. The cross term gives the interference term in the centre which cannot be obtained from the two original Wigner functions.

Comment: @flippiefanus Ok thank you! That's what I figured, but I just wasn't sure.

Comment: You are confusing yourself with Wigner functions. Their mathematics follows that of density matrices to a T. Stick to a simple example of a 2x2 density matrix to see the point. In fact, that should be part of your question clarification, in which point the question would be superfluous.